# ponyORM : how to bypass limit in select

Tags: python, ponyorm

I want to select rows by join several tables on multiples conditions... and it fails. 
`PonyORM` seems to limit the number of conditions in "if statement".

To reproduce, in estore.py / test_queries (PY3.6, PonyORM 0.73) , a **stupid** example:

```
result = select(c for c Customer if c.country!='A' and c.country!='A' and c.country!='A' and c.country!='A' and c.country!='A' and ...)
```

If `Nbr of c.country! = 'A' <= 24`, it works, but `>= 25`, it failed in decompiling.py

How to bypass this limit, annoying for queries with a lot of tables and conditions?

```
    Traceback               
    <module>      site-packages\pony\orm\examples\estore.py 183     
    test_queries  <string>                                    2     
    new_func      site-packages\pony\orm\core.py            460     
    test_queries  site-packages\pony\orm\examples\estore.py 169     
    select        <string>                                    2     
    cut_traceback site-packages\pony\utils\utils.py          58     
    select        site-packages\pony\orm\core.py           5160     
    make_query    site-packages\pony\orm\core.py           5147     
    decompile     site-packages\pony\orm\decompiling.py      32     
    __init__      site-packages\pony\orm\decompiling.py      72     
    decompile     site-packages\pony\orm\decompiling.py      90     
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'list' and 'int'
```

**EDIT :**  as a workaround , we can split the query by adding *.where*

```
result = select(c for c Customer if c.country!='A' and c.country!='A' and c.country!='A' and c.country!='A' and c.country!='A').where(lambda c:c.country!='A' and c.country!='A')
```

Comment: Can you edit in the actual full traceback of the exception?

Answer (score 2):

It was the bug caused new bytecode things from Python 3.6. We've just released the [fix on github](https://github.com/ponyorm/pony/commit/d762dc7c8037929b2c0e4beaad539bcdae15770e).